# unresolved external symbol, PrioAPI What is really missing

Tags: c++

I know, sounds like all the other "unresolved external symbol" issues, but as far as i saw until now all the issues, that I looked through, are about self defined functions, i seam to have a problem with a WINAPI Function...

I'm trying to get the API from Yosts PRIVR running. currently I'm facing the problem that on compilation i get the following error:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol
_BluetoothFindDeviceClose@4
referenced in function "void __cdecl connectedBthAddrs(class std::vector<unsigned __int64,class std::allocator<unsigned __int64> > *)"
 (?connectedBthAddrs@@YAXPAV?$vector@_KV?$allocator@_K@std@@@std@@@Z)
```

Do I understand it right that what is missing is the definition of a_BluethoothFindDeviceClose function? That should be a winSDK function right? So how do i fix this?

While we are at it can someone please tell me, in a comment maybe, what the @4 does imply? I'm pretty sure it is not a line number.

Comment: You need to link with an additional library see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362782(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The @4 thing is a "decorated symbol". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679311(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)